# Simplifying $ 2\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x) + \cos^4(x) + \sin^4(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

who can simplify the following term in a simplest way?

$$ 2\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x) + \cos^4(x) + \sin^4(x)$$

(The answer is 1). Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The general approach would be to search for a suitable transform for this function. In our case the best one probably is the Fourier transform. The trigonometric "laws" are then automatically applied when calculating the function in the Fourier domain. Now you did not ask for this, so I write it in a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $$ 2\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x) + \cos^4(x) + \sin^4(x)$$
>
> $$(a+b)^2=2ab+a^2+b^2$$

$$=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2$$

$$=1^2$$

$$=\boxed{\color{red}1}$$

Answer (score 6):

HINT :

$$2ab+a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2$$
with
$$\cos^2 (x)+\sin^2(x)=1.$$

Comment: Ok, sorry. How could I have overlooked this ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cos^2x\sin^2x + \cos^4x + \sin^4x = (\cos^2x + \sin^2x)^2$$

I'm sure you can work out what $n$ should be. Mathlove already gave you a big clue there!

Comment: you have put $n$ - but it should be $2$...

Comment: @johannesvalks, I've left that deliberately for the OP to work out You've spoilt it now! The downvote was so unnecessary!

Comment: I did not downvoted your post. It appears there are others doing that... I did actually an upvote...

Comment: @johannesvalks, Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer is straight forward but here are some steps if you find helpful
Notice, $$2\cos^2 x\sin^2 x+\cos^4 x+\sin^4 x$$ $$=(\cos^2 x)^2+(\sin^2 x)^2+2(\cos^2 x)(\sin^2 x)$$ Now, assume $\alpha =\cos^2 x$ & $\beta=\sin^2 x$ & apply $\alpha^2+\beta^2+2\alpha \beta=(\alpha+\beta)^2$$$=(\cos^2x+\sin^2 x)^2$$$$=(1)^2=1 \quad (\text{since,}\ \cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1)$$